# Can we consider $\tan^{-1}x$ as an angle in degree?

Tags: notation

When we write $\tan^{-1}x , \sin^{-1}x,...$ is it automatically considered as an angle in **radian** or it can be considered as degree as well?

For example, we have$\;\;\pi-(\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3))=\frac{\pi}4$

But can we say
$\;180^{\circ}-(\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3))=45^{\circ}$
Or it is wrong and it is equal to $180^{\circ}-\frac{3\pi}4$?

Comment: If you regard the $\,^\circ$ symbol as meaning $\frac{\pi}{180}$ then this works

Comment: In higher mathematics, trig functions and inverse trig functions are always considered to use radian measure. Elsewhere, you can do what you want, so long as the rules of the game are made clear to the reader.